# In District 9, why didn't the lost fluid cause any problems?

Tags: district-9

In *District 9*, Christopher Johnson is collecting a black fluid,

> in order to activate the command ship and leave earth.

He only has a small amount, and every drop counts.

[image: Black fluid]

Early in the film, Wilkus accident sprays some of the fluid on his face.

Despite this,

> the command ship is still operable and able to to reach the mothership.

If he didn't need all the fluid, why didn't Christopher leave earlier?

Comment: An abundance of caution, perhaps? If I'm going to drive to the coast, I don't gas up my car with *precisely* the amount of petrol needed and not a drop more...

Answer (score 6):

The Prawn is only able to retreat with his son, rather than the original plan of freeing his entire race.

Thats what the loss of the Fluid meant to him.

Comment: Interesting. Do you have any sources for that?

Comment: I remember this from the film as well, though my memory is that he has to leave his son behind as well, in order to bring help from home, as a direct result of the lost fluid.

Comment: @davejohnson He brings his son but has to leave the main guy behind.

Comment: In the discussion of the unexpected three years until Markus can be "fixed", Christopher Johnson says "I must use all the fluid to move fast." (Seeing the remains at MNU of prawns that had been used in medical experiments gives him new urgency). So the change of plans may have more to do with speed than it does with the loss of fluid.